# Related UL blocks by LI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't even know how to formulate this question... I have 2 UL blocks, each has 10 LI elements, they always going to have the same number of elements, 10, 160, 12, etc., Left block is a floating fixed navigation, and the right block has the content, how do I know know which element is on view so on the left block I add a class as current

```
<div class="leftnav">
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
</div>

<ul>
   <li>Content 1</li>
   <li>Content 2</li>
   <li>Content 3</li>
   <li>Content 4</li>
   <li>Content 5</li>
   <li>Content 6</li>
</ul>
```

So when a user scroll down content 2 show up and navigation li get a class as current... when user clicks on the navigation it scrolls to the content on the right... does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want a scrollspy-like system?  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Comment: @EricN yes and no, yes same functionality, and no, in #scrollSpy it uses ID's anchors, in my case the content is dynamic via web-service, I can't add id's to each li and i can not add A tags to the navigation...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information being dynamic and assuming you can't or don't want to affect the markup, how about....

```
$(window).on('scroll', handleScroll);

function handleScroll (e) {
  var currentLiIndex;
  $('{second ul} li').each(function (i, e) { 
    // loop through all the second li's, 
    // find which is closest to top of the window but below the scroll
    if ($(e).offset().top > scrollY) {
      currentLiIndex = i;
      return false;
    }
  });

  // clear actives
  $(".navigation li").removeClass('active');

  // target the nav li based on the index of the top function
  // and add active class
  $(".navigation li")[currentLiIndex].addClass('active');
}
```